# asp.net MVC responsive design best template

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

i am comparing responsive design templates for my new mvc 4 web app. so far, i am considering
 Bootstrap from twitter and Foundation framework from Zurb.

I just want to know which one is better based on your experience ? Is there any other good option?

thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give my article a read, it should give you a good insight on getting started.
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/responsive-design-using-foundation-with-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: very good read indeed! but you didnt tell how Foundation is better than Bootstrap?

Comment: Foundation has very simple UI style, I find it much easier to override the styles and prevent the "cloned" look of bootstrap (http://builtwithbootstrap.com/).

Thanks for reading!

Comment: There is a new website designated to responsive design and MVC http://www.responsivemvc.net

Answer (score 0):

I tried 3-4 responsive frameworks but found [Twitter Bootstap](http://getbootstrap.com/) the best. Its now also being used in default Microsoft Asp.net templates.